# Order of cancel button in UIAlertView is different in iOS8

Tags: xcode5, uialertview, ios8, ios7.1

I have project supported till iOS7, i run it in **iOS8 device** using **Xcode 5.1**. I found problem in order of cancel button in *UIAlertView*.

**Code**

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                    message:@"Title"
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"Button1",@"Button2",@"Button3",nil];
[alert show];
```

**Output**

[image]

---

**Questions**

1. Why Cancel button location is different in both OS?
2. Is it a new UI changes in iOS8 ? If yes please give me a reference link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>Seems like iOS 8 onward, order of button appearance is the order in which you write them</strike>. In iOS 8 UIAlertView and UIActionSheet are deprecated. Instead use UIAlertController. Following is the reference to it:

[UIAlertController Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/iOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/index.html)

The order in which you add UIAction in UIAlertController is the order in which buttons appear in alert.

**UPDATE:** Ordering of buttons is fixed in iOS 8 Beta 3. Position of 'Cancel' button is always last now.

Comment: Thanks for your answer friend but it is not helping me, I want to build project using XCode5.1 + iOS8, It means i don't want to use latest SDK of iOS8, What i want is that a reference link for UI change coming in UIAlertView's cancel button

Comment: i +1 you, now just checking after done confirmation i will accept your answer